# ClickOnce deployment causes "Application identity is not set" error

Tags: c#, clickonce

I know there are 3 other question Titles similar to this one on SO. My problem is different than others because of the following reason.

```
if (!ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
     UserMessage("Not network deployed", ConsoleColor.Red);
}
```

I am seeing this message after I deployed to my **Website** and install it from the link which opens after the publish finishes. Thus, it is **Network Deployed**.

I put the following line out of the above if statement, in a try catch block.

```
var deployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
```

And I get `Application identity is not set` exception.

FYI, my application is a console application.

**Note**: All the above situations occur after I install from my website. Not in debug mode.